# Conditional GROUP BY result

Tags: mysql, group-by, conditional-statements

I need the query to group by `name` and, if *one* of the `is_new` is `1`, the resulting value should be `1`.

---

Current rows:

```
+--------+--------+
| name   | is_new |
+--------+--------+
| a      |      0 |
| a      |      0 |
+--------+--------+
| b      |      0 |
| b      |      1 |
+--------+--------+
| c      |      1 |
| c      |      1 |
+--------+--------+
```

Expected query result:

```
+--------+--------+
| name   | is_new |
+--------+--------+
| a      |      0 |
| b      |      1 |
| c      |      1 |
+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT name,MAX(is_new) AS is_new FROM <TABLE> GROUP BY name
```

Comment: I was interested in how exactly can you use conditionals with GROUP BY clause (i.e. `if one of the values is "value1" then the GROUP BY result should be "1"`). But this works nonetheless, so I'm going with it. Thanks.

Comment: it think this could be done with `SELECT name,MAX(CASE WHEN is_new='value1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS is_new FROM <TABLE> GROUP BY name`